# calculating expectation of a random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value

I'm reading a probability book which says:

---

we first sample a real number x from a
uniform distribution over the interval [−1, 1]. We next sample a random variable  *s*  .with probability 1/2 we choose *s* to be 1 and otherwise the value will be -1  ,

---

my question is what is the expectation of *s*?
I'm trying to solve it through the basic integral formula and had no success.

Answer (score 1):

The "basic integral formula" becomes a sum for discrete random variables.
Hence you get $$E[s] = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot (-1) = 0$$